# iPhone - Page Scroll View Help, stop different views controllers allocation

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

Currently i have using the PageControl sample code of Apple, in this sample code all the time create new View Controller. Thats why the application memory issues and crash the application.

In my application there are 250 pages to display in paging.

Is there any way to create one or tow view controller and paging that views.

Please Help me..

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0):

The apple's pageControl sample code will keep the current page, left un-visible page, and the right un-visible page. So it will new viewControllers, but I remember it will release other un-usable viewControllers to reduce the memory usage. The maximum viewControllers it keeps in the array are 3.

Comment: thanks for answer, technically you are right, but in test with device memory allocation every time swipe the view right alloc new view controller and increase memory  :(

Comment: Maybe you have some memory leaks, or you can use NSAutoreleasePool to release those autoreleased objects manually.